# How to find similar matching of words in database in java

Tags: java, regex, string-comparison

I have a list of words which are not properly pronounced i.e smartphone is pronounced as smartphon also private as privat.

So I will match the poorly pronounced word with the database which contains the right word. How to do so.

I want to get the word and replace the word with the right word.

```
  poorwords                   rightword            

  privat                      private                


  capabl                       capable

  storag                       storage

  satisfi                      satisfy
```

How to do this. Is their compareTo(String h) method solves my problem?

Comment: Is the error always on the end of the word ? Or is it just for the example ?

Comment: Save these pairs in a map. Then, when you have a key word, replace it with its value. But why don't you use a spelling correction algorithm?

Comment: Something similar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461120/check-how-much-a-string-sounds-like-another-one-in-java

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for this.

Comment: @DeadlyJesus yes always at the end of the word...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you will need a dictionary of valid words and then rank the word being tested against those in the dictionary using [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Answer (score 1):

You can find java library to calculate **Levinshtein distance** at Apache Commons' [StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(CharSequence s, CharSequence t)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))