# java string matching

Tags: java

All that I am doing in my project is taking two values(that I am reading from two different excel  files) and checking how similar they are.! I tried using the pattern and matcher classes which works perfectly fine when both the words are exactly the same (as in organisation and organisation/s). In my data I have say something like (employee and employment), I just need "employ" as the common string between the two, in which case..pattern and matches fails.! I am stuck with this since a week.I have about 700 rows in the first excel file and about 9000 in the other. Each cell value that I am reading into the program using java, I am storing them in two separate variables. Next, i tried using 4 for loops to match word by word and character by character to find only those characters that match between the two.I have pasted the coded for the for loop implementation. Four for loops are like driving me nuts.! Any help in completing this would be greatly appreciated.

```
    String str1 = "Cover for employees of the company";
    String str2 = "Employment Agencies ";
    String str,strfinal;
    String[] count1 = str1.split("\\s+");
    String[] count2 = str2.split("\\s+");
    char[] count11 = str1.toCharArray();
    char[] count22 = str2.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0;i<count1.length;i++)
     {
        for(int j=0;j<count2.length;j++)
        {
            for(int m=0;m<count1[i].length();m++)
            {
                for(int n=0;n<count2[j].length();n++)
                {
                    if(count11[m]==count22[n])
                    {
                         // please look at the logic that I am looking for to implement
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected output: employ

one more concept that I am trying to implement (in order to make my program more efficient) is.. 
cover ----(compared with) employment. First character itself does not match.Implies go to the next word in the second string. Once all words in the second string are traversed and checked for, go to the next word in the first string and compare this word with all the words in the second string.
Okay.. so this is what I am looking for right now.. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You are looking for a soundex comparision. This is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461120/check-how-much-a-string-sounds-like-another-one-in-java