# from free text to list of value

Tags: java, lov, data-quality

I'm implementing a web application with a supscription form (using Java for the backend). In this form there is a field with a dropdown list associated to it. The user has the possibility (with an auto-completion functionality) to select a value from the dropdown list or insert a different value (free text). If the user has entered a value not included in the dropdown list, I would like to verify if the value entered by the user "has the same meaning" to one of the dropdown list in order to standardize it.
Is there any method or product that I could leverage on to perform this "data quality" activity? 
Let me do the following example:

In the dropdown list I've several brands, including LOUIS VITTON.
The user doesn't care avout the value "DOLCE & GABBANA" suggested by the auto-completion functionality and insert "dolce and gabbana".

I would like to have a method/tool that understand that "dolce and gabbana" has the same meaning of "DOLCE & GABBANA".

Hope that is clear.

Thank you

Davide

Comment: What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: Something like a **soundex** comparison.

Comment: At the moment am quite lost I mean that I don't even know what to search, that's why I've posted the question to my favourite community :)

Comment: "&" for "and" is an easy and obvious case to check for.  But what about, say,  "Dollchay y gabanna" for "Dolce & Gabbana"?  How hard are you willing to work to figure out  users' random crap input? I wish you luck in your quest (;->)

Comment: please refer below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461120/check-how-much-a-string-sounds-like-another-one-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds very interesting and practical,
I have a simple solution for this problem .
First you need to identified word or characters that user can insert to conjugate words , you need to remove them and do similar with your  items list and compare the converted (removed extra chars from user input ) with ignoring case with your list items (in which you removed extra chars or words).  to explain
I am taking your values what you have mention in your requirement.
User have entered =>"dolce and gabbana" convetred it as "dolcegabbana" **uservalue**
same time convert your value => DOLCE & GABBANA to "DOLCEGABBANA" **yourValue**
now just compare

**yourvalue.equalsIgnoreCase(user's converted value)=true**.

to make this thing more practical you need to store your list as map in which key part or your map will be converted string .
As given below

ItemMap.put("DOLCEGABBANA","DOLCE & GABBANA")

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this works for DOLCE & GABBANA case but not for tricky cases such as the user is writing "LUIS VITTON" instead of the correct brand "LOUIS VUITTON" ... I search something more "intelligent" :)